How to setup protocol buffers in CMake via FetchContent
How to fully setup protobuff for C++ with using find_package
So far, I've tried this config
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(ProtoCPP)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
include_directories(src/proto)

file(GLOB PROTO_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/proto/*.cc")
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")

set(ABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD ON)

FetchContent_Declare(
        abseil
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git
        GIT_TAG 20240116.2
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(abseil)

FetchContent_Declare(
        protobuf
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git
        GIT_TAG v27.1
)

FetchContent_Declare(protobuf)

add_executable(ProtoCPP ${SOURCE_FILES} ${PROTO_FILES})
target_link_libraries(ProtoCPP)

Project structure

All I want to do I use the protobuf like normal, but this import:
#include "google/protobuf/runtime_version.h"

failed.
How do I install/use it properly, I tried searching everywhere, I can't find how to.

One thing I see is you are doing your CMake commands in a bad order. I mean shouldn't you fetch protobuf before you do the file globbing and not after? Although with that said it's usually not recommended to file glob.

The example I provided was just written from the back of my head, I didnt put much thought into the order. I just wanted to use protobuf and thats it.

You don't actually link ProtoCPP and protobuf together? Your last line is a no-op.

Like I said, this is just a mockup, I just want to know how do I actually compile protobuff generated files with my program
